# How to embed DSL keyword highlighting and code completion into application

Tags: eclipse, groovy, dsl, rule-engine

I am creating custom DSL with groovy for purpose of creating rules (for rule engine). My target audience will be non-programmers.
Something like this:

```
when user visit page "test" within 5.days
 then assign campaign 200
```

I would like to provide my users with at least some kind of text box where they will be able to  create rules using the DSL. To make it simple and professional I am looking for a third party component to help me with the task of keywords highlighting and code completion. I read about  groovy DSL descriptor but apparently thry working only inside eclipse IDE. Is there any way to incorporate required functionality into my application?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of code editor to put in your projects. Check the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors.

You can see a great example: [Console Plugin source code](https://github.com/tuler/grails-console)